# create matrix in row-major fashion in R

Tags: r, matrix, rstudio

I was able to create a matrix in R using the below line of code

```
> A = matrix(c(0:9),ncol=5,nrow=2)
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    2    4    6    8
[2,]    1    3    5    7    9
```

However, I would like my matrix to be created in row-major fashion. That is, I would like my matrix to looks as follows

```
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    8    9
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `A = matrix(0:9,ncol=5,nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)`

Comment: For future reference, you can do e.g. `?matrix` to see all the options for a function, the 'Arguments' section is particularly helpful in listing out the different options you can specify (including `byrow=` in this case.).